# Effect on leakage when paralleling primary turns in a transformer

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a transformer (PL300-104L) that has 2 windings on the primary.  The specifications are given for when the 2 windings are in series: L = 1075uH, leakage = 1.0uH.  What happens if instead I put the 2 primary windings in parallel?  I understand I get half the turns ratio (that's what I want), I understand I get 1/4 the primary inductance (please confirm this is correct).  But what happens to the leakage?

Comment: I guess would happen the same as with primary inductance.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand I get half the turns ratio (that's what I want), I understand I get 1/4 the primary inductance (please confirm this is correct). But what happens to the leakage?

Different windings of a transformer cannot be treated as independent inductors. They are on the same transformer, they are wound around the same core, so they are **magnetically coupled**.

- You get the one primary's inductance times the square of 2 (i.e. 4), if you connect both primaries in series. Because the number of turns will be doubled, and inductance is proportional to square of turns.
- You **won't** get the one fourth of one primary if you connect both primaries in parallel. Instead, the inductance will stay the same: Inductance of one primary alone. Therefore, the number of turns will stay the same as well.
- The DC resistance will be halved if you connect both primaries in parallel (Assuming the same wire i.e. material, thickness, etc is used).
- In parallel connection, a decrease in the net leakage may be expected as per the transformer model but it can stay the same just like the final primary inductance does. Since the leakage depends also the construction of the transformer, and since we don't know how this transformer's windings are placed, I personally can't say anything about the final leakage -- Thinking about the possibility of using a sectional bobbin having both primaries side by side, for example.

For practical usage, you should not care about the leakage as it's already one thousandth of the initial inductance. For most applications, lower than 1% is expected so yours has even lower.

Comment: "You get the square of one primary's inductance if you connect both primaries in series".  I am skeptical of that.  Let C be some constant, L be inductance, and N be the number of turns.  If L = C * N^2, then 4L = C * (2N)^2.  So it appears that doubling the number of turns increases the inductance by a factor of four.  If L was 1uH it doesn't become (1uH) ^2 (which would not make sense from a units standpoint), or even (1u)^2 H = 10^-12 H (which is very small).

Comment: @user4574 sorry. Wrong spelling. My English sometimes goes crazy. I was trying to write "... times the square of the ratio of final over initial turns". Of course it'll be four times the initial when connecting in series. Thanks for pointing out. Fixed.